# Inject "global" state into a module

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.3

I have [a macro system](https://github.com/Thom1729/YAML-Macros) where macros are defined in Python modules. They are invoked elsewhere with various arguments that are passed directly into the functions exported by the macro module.

I would like for the behavior of some macro file to also depend on some global-ish immutable state. This state will be passed as a parameter into the macro engine. When a macro module is loaded, it should be able to access this state.

One way to do this would be to create a stateful module that the macro modules would import. However, this is a bit "too global" -- I would like for this state to be created when the macro engine is invoked and to leave no trace afterward (such as a module with global state). Then, client code could invoke the engine multiple times without fear.

I am currently using `importlib.import_module` to import the macro modules.

Comment: "without fear" of what

Comment: what  language are you using to design the macro engine, python ?

Comment: @randnum-1: If multiple invocations of the macro engine use the same module to manage global state, this could lead to all sorts of trouble. For instance, suppose that I run several threads, each of which runs the macro engine with different arguments. (I actually intend to do this.)

Comment: @PRMoureu: This is for https://github.com/Thom1729/YAML-Macros . I have added a link to the question.

Comment: Could you give us a little more detail on what you've already tried (maybe the relevant section of code)? I'm not entirely sure what you're asking. Depending on exactly what you want, class attributes or a singleton object might be useful.

Comment: You can see the entire implementation here: https://github.com/Thom1729/YAML-Macros/blob/master/src/build.py